# Google Analytics Goal URL, recording ONLY the first time a user hits that page

Tags: google-analytics

In our user sign-up process, conversion is being defined each time a user completes 4 steps and lands on their individual user home page (`/publications\/.*`). The RegEx is functioning properly, however I realized that GA is registering a "conversion" every time a user signs back in and visits that same page for the second time, third time, etc., since that page is just each user's "home" page on return sign-ins.

Is there a way to force GA to recognize the visits ONLY the first time a user hits that page?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

No. You better create a new url for when the process completes, or maybe fire a [virtual pageview](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/asyncMigrationExamples#VirtualPageviews) once the user completes registration.

You can also mark the first step of the process as a required step. You create a URL Goal but add the sign-up form as a required step. The problem with this setp is that it only applies to the funnel view. The total conversions would still count all of them, but when you look at the funnel view you would only see the conversions that went through the required first step.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways I could think of:

1. Eduardo's virtual pageview recorded on a successful sign-up would be
   my number one recommendation.  This pageview will become your Goal
   Conversion URL and will take care of the repeat offenders.
2. Set a cookie for your registered users and have that determine the conversion tracking.